# Prometheus metrics alerting

Tags: alert, prometheus, metrics, prometheus-alertmanager

I have running Prometheus instance which has it's own /metrics endpoint.
This /metrics endpoint provides about 700+ metrics. I'd like to monitor these metrics with Prometheus monitoring stack.
My **question is** which of these metrics are important to monitor Prometheus it selves so I can create alerts out of them. I do not want to create alerts for all of them - just few important.
Thank you for your hints / help in advance.
Here's example Prometheus /metrics endpoint : http://graf.lysator.liu.se:9090/metrics

Comment: Are you asking about meta-monitoring of prometheus ? There is no definite answer to that but you can find many examples on the net (ex: https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html#prometheus-self-monitoring). Note that an alert is useless if you don't understand it or you don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Thank you very much for your post! This is very helpful.